# Learning C: video course recommendation

Tags: c

I'm required to learn C to help a professor of mine with some lab work. I've got only about 2 weeks to get ready. Anyone can recommend a good course/book, but preferably a video course that's thick and decent (like the MIT open courses style), but anything else that you've had good experience with is welcome too.

Thank you all

Comment: for books and online material check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 5):

The Stanford video lectures are interesting.

You can find them here: 
http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=BD4CAF263B15E5E4&search_query=stanford+program+in+c

EDITED: Sorry, but the above link is about Java. For C, see the following videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMzH3tfP6f8&videos=9CyTscpFk5M&playnext_from=TL&playnext=1

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry! I got confused! I think this one is about C though: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMzH3tfP6f8&videos=9CyTscpFk5M&playnext_from=TL&playnext=1

Comment: -1 This is not a C course, it is a "Programming Abstractions" course and they use C++, not C, to teach it.