# Where can I find easy video lessons to learn C Programming for a novice

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning C: video course recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935438/learning-c-video-course-recommendation)

I am looking for a C language video lessons that are easy to understand and follow (something like khan academy style). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The videos available from Harvard's "Intensive Introduction to Computer Science" have been very valuable in helping me learn C.  You can find those videos here: http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/introduction-computer-science